# vim mapping only works with noremap

Tags: vim

I naively wrote this:

```vimrc
" Fast saving and closing current buffer without closing windows displaying the
" buffer
nmap <leader>wq :w!<cr>:Bclose<cr>
```

But it does not work even though there is nothing overwriting this:

```vimrc
n  ,wq           :w!<CR>:Bclose<CR> " result of `map ,wq`
```

It does work though with the following:

```vimrc
nnoremap <leader>wq :w!<cr>:Bclose<cr>
```

I feel like I am missing something pretty basic here.

Link to full conf: https://github.com/AdrienGiboire/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc

It's still messy as I am currently reworking it :)

Comment: mind show/link your config file?

Comment: @Kent, link added as requested :)

Comment: What "does not work"? Is there an error? Does it save, but not close? What happens if you manually type the right hand side of the mapping?

Comment: It happens literally nothing, that I can see at least. If I run commands manually, it works just fine. Hence the fact that it works with `noremap` proves its efficiency or so I think.

Comment: That's interesting. Typing out the keys should be equivalent to the `:nmap`.

Comment: General rule of thumb: Use `noremap` variants unless you have a good reason not too, like for `<Plug>` mappings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this and as far as I can tell it is breaking because of this mapping:

```
nnoremap : ;
```

I believe at runtime it turns your map into

```
;w!<cr>;Bclose<cr>
```

The `noremap` form prevents the `,wq` mapping from mapping the characters within it, so it does not translate `:` to `;` as it does otherwise. This is exactly the kind of thing `noremap` exists to avoid problems with.

The rule I follow in general is to always use the `noremap` forms unless I know a specific reason I *should not*, because there are so many cases like this one that cause problems and are hard to debug.

Comment: Superb. Well done. Now I understand :) I might stick to your rule as well. Thanks!

Comment: The actual rule is pretty simple: use recursive mappings only when you want to se other mappings; use non-recursive mappings otherwise.